# selenium not able to get text which is not inside any tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need to get text 'Error in data format.. ' from below code.

.getText.getAttribute("innerHTML") is not giving me output.
Can someone please help me?

Code:

Browse
Error in data format..

Comment: post the HTML code as well as your automation script that you have tried so far.

Comment: Could you share your tried attempt as well??